# Como atribuir valor de JavaScript em Razor?

Tags: javascript, razor

Tenho uma variável **Razor** `@minhaVarRazor` e gostaria de alterar o valor dela com base em um valor obtido de outra variável, mas que é do **JavaScript**.

```
function setValue(minhaVarJavaScript){
  @minhaVarRazor = minhaVarJavaScript;
}
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não pode ser feito. As marcações do razor são traduzidas em valores HTML no próprio servidor, e a resposta que o cliente recebe da rede (da requisição HTTP) não tem nenhuma marcação razor, só HTML/JS/CSS puros. Como o JavaScript é executado no cliente (pelo browser), e esse não "conhece" razor (incluindo as ruas variáveis), então o que você quer fazer não é possível.